# Postman accessing child objects in Json in a Test

Tags: json, postman

I am trying to access the name object in this Json to put in a local variable in a Postman Test.

Json
{

```
    "Line": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "LineNum": 1,
            "Description": "Custom Design",
            "Amount": 75.00,
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "value": "4",
                    "name": "Design"
                },
                "UnitPrice": 75,
                "Qty": 1,
                "ItemAccountRef": {
                    "value": "82",
                    "name": "Design income"
                },
                "TaxCodeRef": {
                    "value": "NON"
                }
            }
            
        }
        ]
```

}

I am using this code to loop through the Line Array but if I try and go deeper than 1 level Itemref it returns undefined

```
let ProductArray=[];
for (let i=0; i < Line.length; i++) {
//


    ProductArray.push({
     
      "value":Line[i].SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef.name
})
}
```

I have also tried

`'"value":Line[i].SalesItemLineDetail["ItemRef"].name`

`"value":Line[i].SalesItemLineDetail["ItemRef"]["name"]`

all return ItemRef undefined

What is the correct syntax or code?

TIA

Comment: your code works fine , the undefined is coming up because all elements in that array doesn't have "name" attribute

Answer (score 0):

There are just some small pieces missing with your code. I re-create a test and mocked the same JSON data. I just add the missing pieces to your code and the **test was Successful**.

GET Request:

```
//Response body JSON
{
    "Line": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "LineNum": 1,
            "Description": "Custom Design",
            "Amount": 75,
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "value": "4",
                    "name": "Design"
                },
                "UnitPrice": 75,
                "Qty": 1,
                "ItemAccountRef": {
                    "value": "82",
                    "name": "Design income"
                },
                "TaxCodeRef": {
                    "value": "NON"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

// Tests
// Check response body
const res = pm.response.json().Line;

let ProductArray=[];
for (let i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
    const res = pm.response.json().Line;
    ProductArray.push({
      "value":res[i].SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef.name
    })

    // Lets see console.log result
    console.log('Check For:', res[i].SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef.name)
    
    // Set Result to environment variables
    pm.environment.set("variable_key", res[i].SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef.name);
}
```

`console.log` output: **Design** which is also added to environment variables.